# Do I need to add HTTPS registries to Docker daemon?

Tags: docker, https, docker-compose, nexus

I am using private Docker registries for my CI/CD pipeline. These are Docker repositories in my Nexus (NXRM) instance.
Until recently, those repos only had HTTP connectors but after upgrading NXRM (I believe it's supported since 3.18.0), it seems possible to add HTTPS connectors to them. So I tried to add support for both protocols in one of my repos:

[image: HTTP and HTTPS connectors setup for Nexus Docker repos]

Upon reading Docker docs it is my understanding that **only insecure registries should be declared in the Docker Daemon**, but maybe I got that wrong. I tried to figure it out by myself by attempting logins to my registry both with and without the IP address declared in the daemon, but I got 503 Service unavailable both times. I must have an issue elsewhere (working on it right now), so I can't know for sure. Maybe I can't have both connectors enabled at the same time, that's the next lead I'll follow.

**Do I need to declare my Docker registries that support HTTPS in the daemon in order to be able to log in?**

Comment: If your NXRM is running behind a reverse proxy the 503 response might be due to proxy misconfiguration.

Comment: Not if you want docker login to work.. see here:  https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/#deploy-a-plain-http-registry

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use both HTTP and HTTPS connectors at the same time given that they use different connection ports. Whether you have to declare your registry in the daemon depends on your certificate - an insecure registry is one using a self-signed certificate.